# Rails4: @import "my_folder" (with index.css.sass in it) doesn't work anymore, only @import "my_folder/index" does

Tags: import, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

We are in the process of upgrading a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4.0.

We have an `assets/stylesheets/application/index.css.sass` file that loads some other sass files, for example an `assets/stylesheets/layout/index.css.sass` file.

In Rails 3.2, it worked by only doing `@import "layout"`, but in Rails 4.0 we get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /users/sign_in
File to import not found or unreadable: layout.
Load paths:
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/images
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/vendor/assets/images
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/xray-rails-0.1.9/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/xray-rails-0.1.9/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/js-routes-0.9.6/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails-0.0.11/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails-0.0.11/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/jquery-ui-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/images
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/jquery-ui-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/jquery-ui-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/html5-rails-0.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/html5-rails-0.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/cocoon-1.2.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/select2-rails-3.5.0/app/assets/images
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/select2-rails-3.5.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/select2-rails-3.5.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/cleditor-rails-0.1.1/vendor/assets/images
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/cleditor-rails-0.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/cleditor-rails-0.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/fullcalendar-rails-1.6.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/fullcalendar-rails-1.6.4.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-1.0.12/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/jquery-rails-2.1.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/vendor/assets/fonts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/vendor/assets/images
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/images/sprites
  /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@iq/gems/compass-h5bp-0.1.2/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  (in /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/assets/stylesheets/application/index.css.sass:80)
```

When explicitly doing `@import "layout/index"`, it works.

My questions:

1) Why does `@import "layout"` not work anymore in Rails 4.0?

2) Where do all these `CompassRails::SpriteImporter` paths come from? And are they okay, or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `@import 'layout/*'` to load all the files from a folder.

You could also configure some paths manually if the paths are not resolved properly with `config.assets.paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['gemname'].full_gem_path}/app/assets/stylesheets/gemname"`. Then you'll be able to include them from the assets pipeline.

Hope it helps!